# C# API return HTML instead JSON

Tags: c#, json

Don't know why a web request return HTML instead JSON. Can anyone please help.

```
private void Test()
    {
        string url = "https://www.netonnet.no/Category/GetFilteredCategory";

        string json = "{'sectionId':'10978','filter': '[]','sortOrder':-1,'sortBy':0,'pageSize':96,'listType':'10'}";

    string result = "";
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {                
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", json);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Comment: What's the HTML, and what's the returned HTTP status code?

Comment: @stuartd This is the beginning of HTML received '<!DOCTYPE html>' and HTTP status code = 200

Comment: @FabrizioMigotto Yes, I have checked that API is right.

Comment: I checked with the same request - the content type of entity returned is `text/html; charset= utf-8`.you cannot expect json here.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Many thanks, for my knowledge why and which conditions that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your asking an you want it in a specific format you should add

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
```

This will tell the API that you want it in json, but this only works if they can give it to you in that format.

And like Amit Kumar Ghosh said in a comment above, it seems like they don't serve json.